# StackOverFlowError Handling and Java Recovery

Tags: java, exception, stack-overflow

Can anyone please explain how StackOverFlowError work?

I know endless recursion causes StackOverFlowError, but does any other method gets executed after the stack is full? I have handled the error in catch block. I would like to know how java functions or recovers from the error that has been caught.

Sample code:

```
public class Test {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        try {
            show();
        } catch(StackOverflowError e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }    
        System.out.println("After StackOverFlowError");

        display();    
    }

    static void show() {
        show();
    }

    static void display() {
        System.out.println("Hello New Function");
    }    
}
```

And the output is:

> ```
> java.lang.StackOverflowError
>
> After StackOverFlowError
>
> Hello New Function
> ```

​

Comment: Typically you don't recover from `StackOverflowError`, which is a runtime exception.  If you recursion blows up, that's it, fix your code or try running it again under different conditions.

Comment: I think you didn't get the question. StackOverFlowError has been deliberately generated to understand how it works and how java recovers from it. My question is if after endless recursion, the stack is full, technically no other method should be pushed into that stack so how is display() getting called? Did java recover from it?

Comment: Well you caught the exception, are you surprised by something?  The recursion still died, and if you were expecting a result back you probably would not get it.  Typically you would not catch an unchecked exception like `StackOverflowError` in practice.

Comment: Well you caught the exception, are you surprised by something?  The recursion still died, and if you were expecting a result back you probably would not get it.  Typically you would not catch an unchecked exception like `StackOverflowError` in practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, java recovered from it.
When the StackOverflowError is thrown it unwinds the stack through all the show() methods until it gets back to your catch block.  At this point only the main() is left on the stack and you could continue executing your program without issue.

Your call stack will look like:

```
main()
   show()
      show()
         show()...
```

However deep your stack memory allows it to go, when the last show() method gets the exception it throws it to each show method which re-thorws it until it reaches the catch block in your main and the error is printed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim said, you do not handle StackOverflowError, instead if it is possible try better approach like iteration or finish the call stack after several calls.

Comment: I think you didn't get the question. StackOverFlowError has been deliberately generated to understand how it works and how java recovers from it. My question is if after endless recursion, the stack is full, technically no other method should be pushed into that stack so how is display() getting called? Did java recover from it?

Comment: oh, sure it will recover as long you caught the error in the running thread, as shown by your snippet. If you let the error to be thrown to the uppermost calls, then the application/running thread will terminate (system exit) since it got the error and no one handles it.